# Show that function $\mathcal F$ is norm preserving

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces

Fix $N \in \Bbb N$. The function $\mathcal F:(\Bbb C ^N , || \cdot || _2 )\to(\Bbb C ^N , || \cdot || _2 )$ is defined as follows: $$ (\mathcal F (x))_k := \frac 1 {\sqrt N} \sum^N_{j=1} x_j \mathrm {exp} ({2\pi i \frac {(j-1)(k-1)}{N}}) $$

**I now have to show that $\mathcal F$ is norm-preserving.**

I had the following idea: 
I've shown that **$\mathcal F$ is linear** and wanted to **show that the standard base is projected into another orthonormal base** (orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product) **so that $\mathcal F$ would be unitary and therefore norm-preserving**. But I don't know how to show that the image of the standard base:$$(\mathcal F (\mathrm e_l))_k= \frac 1 {\sqrt N} \mathrm {exp} ({2\pi i \frac {(j-1)(k-1)}{N}})$$ forms an orthonormal base.

Any ideas on how to show this or maybe a completley diffenrent approach? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$\omega_j=e^{\frac{2\pi i\,j}N},\ \ \ j=0,1,\ldots,N-1,$$ the $N^{\rm th}$-roots of unity.

For simplicity, I'll renumber the indices of $x$ and $k$ to $0,\ldots,N-1$. So, with $e_0,\ldots,e_{N-1}$ the canonical basis, 
$$
\mathfrak F(e_j)=\frac1{\sqrt N}\,\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\,\omega_j^k\,e_k.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\langle \mathfrak F(e_j),\mathfrak F(e_s)\rangle
&=\frac1N\,\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{t=0}^{N-1}
\omega_j^k\overline{\omega_s^t}\langle e_k,e_t\rangle=\frac1N\,\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}
\omega_j^k\overline{\omega_s^k}\\ \ \\
&=\frac1N\,\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\omega_j^k\omega_s^{-k}=\frac1N\,\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\omega_{j-s}^k=\delta_{j,s}.
\end{align}When $j=s $, all terms in the last sum are one; and when $j\ne s $, the sum is zero.